# Fiddlercore: how to block and redirect sites

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

Fiddler core .net api proxy server captures network traffic.

1. how to redirect any http/https url to another site.?

   suppose if I browse yahoo.com, then proxy server should redirect to another site such as wikipedia.com. Browser should open wikipedia instead of yahoo.com.
2. how to block any web site.?

   suppose when I hit espncricinfo.com in browser, then site must be blocked and stopped its session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These topics are well-covered in the [Fiddler book](http://fiddlerbook.com/) and in numerous tutorials around the web.

Inside your `BeforeRequest` handler, add code that examines the request and returns a redirect (or an error page)

```
if (oSession.urlContains("whatever"))
{
   oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
   oS.oResponse.headers.SetStatus(307, "Redirect");
   oS.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "nocache";
   oS.oResponse["Location"] = "http://newurl/";
   oS.utilSetResponseBody("<html><body>sending request elsewhere</body></html>"); 
   return;
}
```

Comment: how to block web site??

Comment: There are many ways. For instance, you could set the status code to `451` and put a "Blocked site" message in the body text.