# Proxy Server vs Hosts File vs Firewall, which to programmatically block websites in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, proxy

I'm creating a WPF application in C# which when the user runs the application would like the ability to block users from accessing certain websites and redirect them, however, I'm torn between which method I should use to complete this feature.

I've done research, and discovered that:

**Hosts File** - it partially works, for websites owned by small businesses (with a single IP) as it successfully blocks it and redirects to assigned IP, however, larger companies such as Facebook, Google who have multiple IPs it fails to block them and unless you gain Admin access you don't have the authority to edit it.

**Proxy Server** - I'm hesitant to attempt this due to my limited skill set but if this is the only way to succeed than I'll take this method as it seems to be the well suited method to what I'm trying to achieve.

**Windows Firewall** - I've seen that you can programmatically enable and disable this feature, allowing you to pass websites to block but if the users not using the Windows Firewall than subsequently, you cannot use this firewall.

Is the Proxy Server the way to go in terms of blocking and redirecting websites using C#, as I'll be able to not require Admin access nor be limited to only blocking websites with a single IP (unlike Facebook and Google) or am I able to use the Hosts File to block Facebook?

Comment: Why is the "I'm creating a WPF application in C#" relevant? Is it only when your app is running that you want to prevent access to the sites?

Comment: Yes - Ill add that in.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for the [serverfault site](https://serverfault.com/), because it's not specifically about programming but rather about how to block a website on a client computer.

Comment: Host file can be easily bypassed, you can get to public DNS servers, do a dns query and then access via IP address. Windows firewall, you are right, if user has rights it can be asily bypassed. there are git repos that implment proxy server in c#, you could start checking for them. The proxy approach in c# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481955/how-to-monitor-and-change-http-network-traffic-without-using-proxy

Comment: I will post it within there. I just saw it as specifically how to do it programmatically using c#.

Comment: I would suggest that if you go to the c# proxy, edit this question and add some coding you have problems with. Do note that there are free transparent proxies that can be easily configured without need of developing anyting

Comment: Alright, I'll get some specific examples of my code and add it.

Comment: [FiddlerCore](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) is a pre-built proxy library - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384263/fiddlercore-how-to-block-and-redirect-sites as used by the popular [Fiddler tool](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: As a note @dymanoid my question was put on hold on the serverfault site as it was deemed off topic.